# How fread() and fwrite works in c programming

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

I am working on a database flat file project using c language. I have created a structure with few members. I am using fwrite() to write them in binary file and fread() to fetch the data. My two major question

1st can we write structure in text file? I have seen no good example. Is it practically wrong to write it in text format? when I write using "w" instead of "wb" I get the text format but with some extra words.

2nd how these fread() & fwrite works(). They operate on a block of data how they get the address of next block. I mean we do have the pointer but file doesnt have any address so how the pointer go to next block?

Comment: No, you cannot read/write binary structures if the file is not open in binary mode. Clearly you need to do some research on how filesystems work and how OS APIs access the filesystem.  This is outside the scope of the `fread()`/`fwrite()` implementations, which delegate to the OS for the actual file access.

Comment: okay thanks for the input:) .should i use fgets/fputs? to write as text format

Comment: If you want random access to the data then implement `fread/fwrite` (but it will misfire if the structs contain pointers). If you want to read in the whole data set, process it, and rewrite the file, text is good, by `fprintf/fgets` and `sscanf`. Data stored as binary records is often not portable, and, if your program breaks, the filed data is useless. Whereas the text file is human readable, so it is much easier to write new functions to read the data into another program. I have worked on projects where the client insisted that the data files must be spreadsheet compatible too, CSV format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1st can we write structure in text file ? i have seen no good example
>   .is it practically wrong to write it in text format ?when i write
>   using "w" instead of "wb" i get the text format but with some extra
>   words

Imagine your structure contains some integers inside. Now if you write them using `fwrite`, these integers will be written in file in binary format. 
If you try to interpret this as text, this won't work, text editor will try to interpret the binary values as characters - which will most likely not work as you expect.

e.g. if your structure contains integer 3, when written using `fwrite`, it will be stored as

```
00000000 0000000 0000000 00000011 (3 in binary)
```

assuming big endian notation. Now if you will try to read above using a text editor, of course you will not get desired effect.

Not saying anything about the padding bytes which maybe inserted in your structure by compiler.

> 2nd how these fread() & fwrite works(). They operate on a block of
>   data how they get the address of next block. I mean we do have the
>   pointer but file doesnt have any address so how the pointer go to next
>   block?

This is most likely taken care of using OS.

PS. I suggest you read more about serialization, and try to understand difference between text and binary files.

Comment: consider an example where i fetch a detail of an employee from such file and want to write it on a file as text for some reportgeneration .should i use fread and frite  to write complete structure or write individual member of structure one by one

Comment: @ekaf use fwrite/fread for binary data, and text functions for text data. Read more about serialization

Comment: @ekaf I suggest you also understand difference between text and binary files